# ejecutar un input multi-range de un formulario desde el DOM

Tags: javascript, css, formularios, dom, input

tengo un formulario en el index.html,  por una consulta que contempla un rango de precios. y el script en el mismo código.
Luego quité de ese formulario, el input de multi-range , para que se pueda hacer después de la consulta, con los valores obtenidos, como máximo y minimo, porque son muy variables, como para definirlos de antemano los que irían por defecto.
Entonces mi intención es pasarlo al archivo de funciones.js , donde iría otro formulario para filtrar la busqueda entre los resultados obtenidos.
Separado, asi, el  en el index.html y el input en funciones.js, no funciona.

tambien hay otra cosa , a la primera visualización, aparece el color azul de progreso , como lo copié por defecto un valor mínimo y máximo. Que yo puse esos valores en 0 y el máximo, no en el medio. Quisiera que apareciera de entrada todo azul.

```
   rangoPrecios = '<div class="price-input">'

        + '<div class="field">'
        + '<span>Min</span>'
        + '<input type="number" class="input-min" value="' + precioMin + '" id="input-min">'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="separator">-</div>'
        + '<div class="field">'
        + '<span>Max</span>'
        + '<input type="number" class="input-max" value="' + precioMax + '" id="input-max">'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div></div>'
        + '<div class="slider" >'
        + '<div class="progress" ></div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="range-input">'
        + '<input type="range" class="range-min" min="' + precioMin + '" max="' + precioMax + '" value="' + precioMin + '" step="500" id="range-min">'
        + '<input type="range" class="range-max" min="' + precioMin + '" max="' + precioMax + '" value="' + precioMax + '" step="500" id="range-max">'
        + '</div>'
```

En le index.html

```
 const rangeInput = document.querySelectorAll(".range-input input"),
 priceInput = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input input"),
 range = document.querySelector(".slider .progress");
 let priceGap = 1000;



 priceInput.forEach(input =>{
     input.addEventListener("input", e =>{
         let minPrice = parseInt(priceInput[0].value),
         maxPrice = parseInt(priceInput[1].value);
    
         if((maxPrice - minPrice >= priceGap) && maxPrice <= rangeInput[1].max){
        if(e.target.className === "input-min"){
            rangeInput[0].value = minPrice;
            range.style.left = ((minPrice / rangeInput[0].max) * 100) + "%";
        }else{
                 rangeInput[1].value = maxPrice;
                range.style.right = 100 - (maxPrice / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
             }
         }
     });
 });

 rangeInput.forEach(input =>{
     input.addEventListener("input", e =>{
         let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput[0].value),
         maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput[1].value);

         if((maxVal - minVal) < priceGap){
             if(e.target.className === "range-min"){
                 rangeInput[0].value = maxVal - priceGap
             }else{
                 rangeInput[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
             }
         }else{
             priceInput[0].value = minVal;
             priceInput[1].value = maxVal;
             range.style.left = ((minVal / rangeInput[0].max) * 100) + "%";
             range.style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
         }
     });
 });
 </script>
```

El formulario para la consulta sobre los resultados obtenidos, esta todo en el DOM.

dejo el link al ejemplo como esta ahora en el formulario
https://jsfiddle.net/hernan527/gpmohzqt/

Gracias

Comment: Hola, para que tu slider sea todo azul, modifica aquí: `.slider .progress{}` colocando estas propiedades **left: 0%;  right: 0%;**

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.  La primer consulta no es tan importante porque además de esta versión, tengo otra en angular. Ya preguntaré si en esa tengo problemas.